# Javascript OnChange Script - Stop Form Submission

Tags: javascript, onchange

I have a project im working on, that needs a javascript OnChange Script for a dropdown box on media upload page.

I have a drop-down box with 2 options -'Yes' and 'No'. If the user selects 'No' i don't want the form to submit and possibly display a message saying why.

Is anyone able to provide a script to do this? I have to enter this on the attribute itself (eah attribute has the ability to have a OnChange script), i can change the attribute references to the specific ones needed. More of a general 'formula' for the script is needed.

Maybe i'm too vague and its not possible to make on the information i have given you.

Thanks in advance,
T.

Comment: javascript is not java!!!

Comment: It would be easier for us to answer if you provide some code.

Comment: I don't have code per say, this is something i did for automatically filling in a text box based on the dropdown option chosen.

Comment: If(this.value=='46' &&
Document.getElementById('field705').value=="0
{
Document.getElementById('Field705').value='N/A';
}
Else if (this.value=='46' &&
Document.getElementById('field705').value=='N/A')
{
Document.getElementById('field705').value='';
}

Comment: I'm not sure how i would do something similar stopping the form submitting

Answer (score 0):

first, write javascript code like this

```
<script>
function output()
{
    var input = document.getElementById('input').value;
    if(input==0){       
    alert("WHY???");
    document.getElementById("out").value="why?";
    }else{
    document.getElementById("out").value="Ok";
}


}
</script>
```

and for the html code

```
<form>
    <select name="input" id="input" onchange="output()">            
        <option value="1">Yes</option>
        <option value="0">No</option>
    </select> 
    <input type="text" id="out" name="out">
</form>
```

note: javascript not java